# Free cross-platform cpu benchmark software

Tags: cross-platform, command-line, benchmarking

I'm looking for a free cpu benchmark software.

- cross platform (windows, linux, mac)
- command line (no gui for headless linux)
- free or open-source

It does not need to be accurate, a rough number is fine. Or I would consider just writing a crude test in Python.

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head, I would suggest the [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/)

tldr: GPL OS X, Windows, Linux, Free BSD, Solaris, etc. **everything you need**

> The Phoronix Test Suite is the most comprehensive testing and
>   benchmarking platform available that provides an extensible framework
>   for which new tests can be easily added. The software is designed to
>   effectively carry out both qualitative and quantitative benchmarks in
>   a clean, reproducible, and easy-to-use manner.
>
> The Phoronix Test Suite is based upon the extensive testing and
>   internal tools developed by Phoronix.com since 2004 along with support
>   from leading tier-one computer hardware and software vendors. This
>   software is open-source and licensed under the GNU GPL.
>
> Originally developed for automated Linux testing, support to the
>   Phoronix Test Suite has since been added for Apple OS X, Microsoft
>   Windows, BSD, and Solaris operating systems, among other POSIX
>   compliant platforms such as GNU Hurd. The Phoronix Test Suite consists
>   of a lightweight processing core (pts-core) with each benchmark
>   consisting of an XML-based profile and related resource scripts. The
>   process from the benchmark installation, to the actual benchmarking,
>   to the parsing of important hardware and software components is
>   heavily automated and completely repeatable, asking users only for
>   confirmation of actions.

Also, from their Features page,

> Through another Phoronix Test Suite module it is possible to log in real-time various system sensors like the CPU temperature, the battery power consumption, disk read/write speeds, and numerous other sensors.

Comment: It does NOT support Windows.

Comment: @rustyx, yes it does. It lists support for Windows on its main page...